# Cypress data-testid not found

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am running a cypress test on a remote web app and the cy.get method fails to capture elements based on their data-testid .
This is a sample of the tests that I want to run :

```
describe('test: deny', () => {
  it('I can deny', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.deepskydata.com/');
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").click();

  });
});
```

Here the button with data-testid='uc-accept-all-button' is not found by cy.get.
Also `cy.get('button')` doesn't work despite that there are multiple button elements in the DOM.
Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you want to click is for privacy settings.

The problem is this section of the page isn't consistently displayed, once you click the "Accept All" button it may not display on the next run.

To avoid the problem, you should poll for the button inside the **shadow root** container element before attempting to click.

```js
function clickPrivacySettingsButton(attempt = 0) {

  // Poll for 4 seconds
  if (attempt === 40) {
    cy.log('No Accept All button to click')
    return
  }

  cy.get('#usercentrics-root', {log:false}).then($privacySettings => {

    const prvivacyShadow = $privacySettings.shadowRoot   // get shadow root 
    const $acceptAllButton = Cypress.$(prvivacyShadow) 
      .find('[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')      // look for button 

    if ($acceptAllButton.length === 0) {
      cy.wait(100, {log:false})
      clickPrivacySettingsButton(++attempt)
    } else {
      cy.get('#usercentrics-root')
        .shadow()
        .find('[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')
        .click()
      cy.log('Dismissed Accept All button')
      return
    }
  })
}

cy.visit('https://www.deepskydata.com/')
clickPrivacySettingsButton()
```

**Notes**

- You cannot just use Cypress **includeShadowDom** setting, because the shadow root may or may not exist.
- You will have to apply `cy.wait()` in small increments to effectively poll for the Privacy Settings section.

Answer (score 1):

I could see that there is a Shadow DOM in your app. TO make sure cypress traverses through the shadow DOM, in your cypress config file write:

```js
includeShadowDom: true
```

Your cypress.config.js should look like this:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...
  },
  ...
  includeShadowDom: true
})
```

Then in your test, you can directly write:

```js
describe('test: deny', () => {
  it('I can deny', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.deepskydata.com/')
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").should('be.visible').click()
  })
})
```

Avoid using `cy.wait()` as these can make the tests flaky. Instead use a visible assertion to first check that the element is visible and then click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a test to check the banner exists for a user meeting certain conditions.

Otherwise, you can bypass this modal, with correct permissions of course, by making a making a graphQL mutation `saveConsents`, so you will not need to making any checks at the UI level.

Note: you should choose your method of recursing and allow `failOnStatusCode`.

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'url-endpoint',
  auth: 'any-authorization',
  body: {
     operationName: 'saveConsents',
     query: 'graphQL mutation query'
  }
  variables: 'variables-if-needed',
  failOnStatusCode: false, // to allow recurse
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this would work but the goal is to test the whole workflow from the user's point of view and not to bypass the issue.